# javascript error from inside iframe on telerik control event

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, telerik

During the execution of my web application I have to call an external web app over which I have no control.

Normally, everything works fine, however when I put said external application inside an iframe to give the illusion of it being "local" I get javascript errors when clicking radcombobox items: unable to get property 'documentelement' of undefined or null reference.

This problem only occours when using IE10, and only when inside an iframe. Other browsers show no problems of any kind.

Edit: The iframe src property points to a blank page that calls my callback methods in the pageload to redirect to the external application.

Here's the iframe code:

> ```
> <iframe width="980px" height="690px" frameborder="0"
> src="IndexToTarget.aspx"></iframe>
> ```

And the method inside the page load of IndexToTarget.aspx:

> ```
> if (!IsPostBack) 
>        {
>            CallTargetApplication();
>        }
> ```

As I already said everything works fine when I call *CallTargetApplication()* and the page opens in a normal browser page. Opening the same page inside an iframe though causes javascript errors, as explained above.

edit:
CallTargetApplication() in the end does a "simple" redirect,

> HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(url.ToString(), false);

the URL is dinamically put together at runtime.

Comment: Without seeing any code, we would just be guessing.

Comment: This isn't really enough code to see what's going on.  We would really need to see `CallTargetApplication`.